# Maven to SpringBoot conversion failed

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I'm converting my working maven application to spring boot, I added parent dependencies and plugin, also I added SpringBootApplication annotation in main class and started the app with SpringApplication.run(... but it gave me a lot of errors. What things could go wrong and what should I check/change?

Error messages

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.1)

2022-08-01 12:46:12.316  INFO 36129 --- [           main] PlantUMLDemoMain                         : Starting PlantUMLDemoMain using Java 17.0.2 on MacBook-Air-uzivatela-Miso.local with PID 36129 (/Users/misacina/SCR/GitLab/PlantUML/target/classes started by misacina in /Users/misacina/SCR/GitLab/PlantUML)
2022-08-01 12:46:12.323  INFO 36129 --- [           main] PlantUMLDemoMain                         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-08-01 12:46:12.503  WARN 36129 --- [           main] ionWarningsApplicationContextInitializer : 

** WARNING **: Your ApplicationContext is unlikely to start due to a @ComponentScan of the default package.


2022-08-01 12:46:14.608  WARN 36129 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/Users/misacina/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.7.1/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.1.jar!/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/r2dbc/ConnectionFactoryConfigurations$PoolConfiguration.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.r2dbc.ConnectionFactoryConfigurations$PoolConfiguration due to io/r2dbc/spi/ValidationDepth not found. Make sure your own configuration does not rely on that class. This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
2022-08-01 12:46:14.618  INFO 36129 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-08-01 12:46:14.662 ERROR 36129 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/Users/misacina/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.7.1/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.1.jar!/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/r2dbc/ConnectionFactoryConfigurations$PoolConfiguration.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.r2dbc.ConnectionFactoryConfigurations$PoolConfiguration due to io/r2dbc/spi/ValidationDepth not found. Make sure your own configuration does not rely on that class. This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:457) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:316) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:276) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:128) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:296) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:207) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:175) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at PlantUMLDemoMain.main(PlantUMLDemoMain.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.r2dbc.ConnectionFactoryConfigurations$PoolConfiguration due to io/r2dbc/spi/ValidationDepth not found. Make sure your own configuration does not rely on that class. This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:54) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:88) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:71) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.isConditionMatch(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:512) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.isCandidateComponent(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:495) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:430) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/r2dbc/spi/ValidationDepth
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3402) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2504) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder$Bean.getSorted(JavaBeanBinder.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder$Bean.addProperties(JavaBeanBinder.java:132) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder$Bean.<init>(JavaBeanBinder.java:127) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder$Bean.get(JavaBeanBinder.java:226) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:54) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$bindDataObject$5(Binder.java:476) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withIncreasedDepth(Binder.java:590) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withDataObject(Binder.java:576) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.access$300(Binder.java:537) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindDataObject(Binder.java:474) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindObject(Binder.java:414) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:343) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:332) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:262) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:223) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.r2dbc.ConnectionFactoryConfigurations$PooledConnectionFactoryCondition.getMatchOutcome(ConnectionFactoryConfigurations.java:138) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.r2dbc.spi.ValidationDepth
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    ... 45 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: did you do a maven update?

Comment: do you mean reload?

Comment: no Update - as in `mvn clean install -U`

Comment: yeah i did it but didnt help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, problem was that i keep all my classes in the main "java" folder and it shouldnt be that way.